# Is it cost-effective to store images inside a folder rather than the Google Cloud storage?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

When a user uploads an image, it is stored locally inside my project folder, inside a folder called uploads.

When I deploy my website to the App Engine, images are still being stored inside the upload folder. If the website attracts more users, there could be up to millions of images stored there.

Is this effective cost/price wise ?

Or should I upload the images to the google cloud storage ?

(Apparently, the images are stored as "binary files". At least that's what GCP tells me when I navigate inside the source code to my uploads folder. All images display fine though).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In App Engine, the local filesystem that your application is deployed to is not writeable. [link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/)

Google introduced Direct File Uploads but are limited to a combined size of 32MB. [link](https://gae-php-tips.appspot.com/2015/03/09/direct-file-uploads-for-php-5-5/).

You should upload your files/assets to Google Cloud Storage (or any other cloud service).

Comment: I was actually able to write data in it. But the 32MB is duly noted. Thank you for the quick answer :)

Comment: in flexible you can write, but wil span across your instances disks, not a single spot.

Comment: Ok :) When do you think they will add eu support to node.js ? Any ideas ?